# Deploy an app to Heroku that isnt in the project root?

Tags: heroku

I need to deploy a node application that isn't in the root of my project.

My project is similar to this: https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/react-fullstack-graphql/tree/master/advanced

In the root of the project is a React app but I dont want to deploy this. In a folder called “server” there is my node server and this is what I need to deploy to Heroku.

When I deploy Heroku appears to run `npm run start` on the top level package.json. How can I make Heroku ignore this and just run the package.json in the `/server` folder?

Update: Ive created a Procfile in my project root with the following:

```
web: ./server npm run start
```

But when I deploy I get an application error:

```
2018-07-05T12:41:51.627168+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user MYEMAIL@gmail.com
2018-07-05T12:41:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-05T12:42:02.176695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./server npm run start`
2018-07-05T12:42:04.817337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-05T12:42:04.701159+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: ./server: Is a directory
2018-07-05T12:42:04.782252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2018-07-05T12:42:11.974345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=DEPLOY-NAME.herokuapp.com request_id=c2cba42e-80af-4b16-95sdfdfd-2918 fwd="86.343.251.15" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: See example of a project that has in its root two folders one for server and one for react-ui and it is deployed to heroku:
https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node#user-content-deploy-to-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this behaviour by defining a `Procfile` that overrides `start`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type

Comment: Ive played around with the Procfile (see my updated answer) but I cant find much documentation on how to use it with node. How do i run npm install and then npm run start?

Comment: The way Heroku works is that you would normally have a install step which creates the container it will run when it starts, this is where `npm i` would be called, so you would need to customise this step to get it run `npm i` within the `server` directory as well.

Comment: In your example above it's failing because it's trying to run `./server` like a script at the beginning, but this is actually the path you want to run npm within. So for your purposes you could have `cd ./server && npm run start` (you could also have the start script do `npm i` before hand), but I see from your accepted answer you've decided to split the project up, which is a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Check out `heroku-prebuild` script. I have an API app and a react app that are both served by Express but in different folders. Put `package.json` in the root and use `heroku-prebuild` to move around to other folders.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "cd app && npm install && npm run build && cd .. && cd api && npm install",
    "start": "cd api && npm start"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use buildpacks, this solution is probably the cleaner one.

You just have to use this custom Buildpack :
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
heroku config:set PROJECT_PATH=projects/nodejs/frontend

Deploy your project to Heroku.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive messaged Heroku support and they pretty much said they don't support deploying a node app that's not in the project root.

Im going to split my project up but you could probably do it with git subtree.

Comment: git subtree works great as long as you don't try to use the [Heroku Button](https://www.heroku.com/elements/buttons) to deploy your app.